# Is there a way to define S3 connection details programmatically in Flink?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

According to the Flink documentation when reading data from S3 the configuration is set on a *cluster* level. This is by setting up your authentication on the flink-conf.yaml file (which would require a restart of the cluster) or by pointing flink to a valid hadoop file, which also requires a jvm/yaml argument. Is there a way to set this programmatically, such that different jobs could have different auth credentials?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [S3AsyncClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3AsyncClient.html) which you can use to programmatically define what region/bucket to connect to for each job.

Kotlin Example:

```
val s3Client = S3AsyncClient
                .builder()
                .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
                .build()
```